# Suddenly cannot print .odt files

Tags: printing, libreoffice

My HP Photosmart 5520e will no longer print Libreoffice files.  It will print TB messages,.pdf files. Use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and always install security fixes and updates. Would appreciate help; am a newby and do not use command line function.

Comment: What happens when you try to print a .odt file?

Comment: The attempt is labeled "Held"  in the printer que. Clicking on  "release selected jobs" doesn't help. I sometimes get, I think, a msg like"printer not connected to local device."  But, the printer app on my laptop says "connected to localhost." BTW, printer and laptop connected wirelessly.